# Publisher div not showing in opentok cordova plugin in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, opentok

I have implemented opentok cordova plugin inside my Ionic 3 app, I am able to make a video call and in one of my devices i can see the picture in picture style view which shows both the Divs but in my other device i am able to see only one div which has the video of the counterpart, I cannot see the div which has the video stream of the front camera.

Below is my code -

```
  startVideoCall = (sessionData?: any) => {
    this.callStarted = true;
    this.sessionId = sessionData.sessionId;
    this.token = sessionData.token;


    var publisherOptions = {
      insertMode: 'append',
      showControls: true,
      style: {
        buttonDisplayMode: "on",
        nameDisplayMode: "on",
      },
      width: 100,
      height: 150
    };

    var subscriberOptions = {
      insertMode: 'append',
      insertDefaultUI: true,
      showControls: true,
      style: {
        buttonDisplayMode: "on",
        nameDisplayMode: "on",
      },
      width: this.platform.width(),
      height: (this.platform.height() - 40)
    };

    this.session = OT.initSession(this.apiKey, this.sessionId);
    this.publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', publisherOptions);

    if (this.session && this.publisher) {
      this.session.on({
        streamCreated: (event: any) => {

          this.callConnected = true; 
          this.subscriberObj = this.session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', subscriberOptions);
          console.log("subscriberObj==================>", this.subscriberObj);
          OT.updateViews();
        },
        streamDestroyed: (event: any) => {
          console.log(`Stream ${event.stream.name} ended because ${event.reason}`);
          this.session.disconnect();
          OT.updateViews();
          this.navCtrl.pop();
        },
        sessionConnected: (event: any) => {
          console.log("sessionConnected " + event + "his.publisher==>", this.publisher);
          if (!sessionData.isSubscriber) {
            let player_ids = [];
            player_ids.push(sessionData.userDetails.lastLoginDeviceToken);
            this.oneSignal.sendNotification(player_ids, "Incoming Call", sessionData);
          }
          this.session.publish(this.publisher);
        },
        sessionDisconnected: (event: any) => {
          console.log("The session disconnected. " + event.reason);
          this.session.disconnect();
          this.navCtrl.pop();
        },
      });

      this.session.connect(this.token, (error: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(`There was an error connecting to the session ${error}`);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Following is my HTML

```
<ion-content padding style="background-color: black;">
  <div *ngIf="callStarted">
    <div id="subscriber">
    </div>
    <div id="publisher">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4 *ngIf="!callConnected && !isIncomingCall" class="connecting-text">Connecting...</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4 *ngIf="isIncomingCall" class="connecting-text">Incoming call</h4>
  </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer class="controls-icon" *ngIf="showAcceptRejectButtons">
  <ion-icon class="accept-circle-icon rippleEffect" (click)="acceptButtonCall()"></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon class="reject-circle-icon rippleEffect" (click)="rejectButtonCall()"></ion-icon>
</ion-footer>
```

I can't get it working as i have found no documentations as such. I want to show both divs on both the device.

Comment: Before you start the call.  Did you see the front camera in the div? Did you check that the subscriber div is not behind the publisher? Maybe changing the subscriber <-> publisher div order could help.

Comment: The div is there it is getting overlapped.  I tried swapping the order of the divs but that didn't help